# Maximum call stack size exceeded loading tile layers in bing maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps, bing

I'm making a web application in which I'm using bing maps with lots of tile layer, in the worse case the application have to load 16 layers.
After playing around moving the map the error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" always show up.
Any suggestion on of to resolve this problem?
Feel free to ask any questions, I will answer them as soon as possible.

Comment: I got this problem one time when the console output had too much to show. Did you see a lot of informations in your console ?

Comment: You may want to review this article for best results wit this site.  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: nope, It happen when I show and hide the layers

Comment: Can you test against the experimental branch. The team has been doing a lot of memory improvements recently in the experimental branch. These should be in the main release branch by the end of March.